# My c# code is not able to import the p12 certificate and authenticate and shows error invalid credentials

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wsdl

I have a wsdl server running with my client. We have 2 services, the 1st services is to get the user token by validating using the username and password provided to us. we are able to receive the token. now when we come to the second service we are supposed to pass the Outlet Id, User ID, Provider ID, we are passing that and we are supposed to use p12 or pfx certificates (the certificates are avaliable with us in a folder) and in this 2nd service case the userid and password to authenticate are the Token and another password respectively. But we are not able to call the certificate and pass it on the server along with the userid, password and the 3 Provider Datas mentioned earlier (Outlet ID, Provider ID & User ID). Kindly help us in passing the certificates to the wsdl server. When we use SoapUi we have to manually add the WS Security Configuration and keystore(the jks certificate) and it works there but how do we do that in c#?

I have tried running it on SoapUi it works fine with the certificate but without it, the code will show the same invalid credentials error

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.ServiceModel.Security;
using System.ServiceModel.Security.Tokens;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += delegate { return true; };

                ServiceReference1.AuthenticateAndGetUserDetailsResponse responseObject;

                using (ServiceReference1.SecurityPortTypeClient client = new ServiceReference1.SecurityPortTypeClient())
                {
                    ServiceReference1.ItemsChoiceType[] objArray = new ServiceReference1.ItemsChoiceType[2];
                    objArray[0] = ServiceReference1.ItemsChoiceType.UserId;
                    objArray[1] = ServiceReference1.ItemsChoiceType.Password;

                    string[] itemArray = new string[2];

                    itemArray[0] = "AZAE022";
                    itemArray[1] = "LZDE238a";
                    ServiceReference1.AuthenticateAndGetUserDetailsRequest request = new ServiceReference1.AuthenticateAndGetUserDetailsRequest();
                    request.UserLoginDetails = new ServiceReference1.UserLoginDetailsType()
                    {
                        ChannelType = ServiceReference1.ChannelType.PORTAL,
                        ChannelTypeSpecified = true,
                        IPAddress = "192.168.100.26",
                        ItemsElementName = objArray,
                        Items = itemArray
                    };
                    responseObject = client.AuthenticateAndGetUserDetails(request);
                }

                using (HotelService.HotelEventManagementServicePortTypeClient client = new HotelService.HotelEventManagementServicePortTypeClient())
                {
                    HotelService.SubmitHotelEventRequest request = new HotelService.SubmitHotelEventRequest();
                    HotelService.HotelBookingType hotelBookingType = new HotelService.HotelBookingType();
                    hotelBookingType.ProviderData = new HotelService.ProviderDataType() { OutletId = "12355790", ProviderId = "AZAE", UserId = "AZAE022" };
                    hotelBookingType.PersonData = new HotelService.BookingPersonDataType()
                    {
                        Birth = new HotelService.BirthType()
                        {
                            Place = "India",
                            Date = new DateTime(1983, 12, 2)
                        },
                        CountryofResidence = "India",
                        FamilyName = "Family",
                        Gender = HotelService.GenderType.Male,
                        GenderSpecified = true,
                        GivenName = "Name",
                        IdDocumentData = new HotelService.BookingIdDocumentDataType()
                        {
                            DocumentExpiryDate = new DateTime(2022, 12, 31),
                            DocumentExpiryDateSpecified = true,
                            DocumentIssueAuthority = "Government of India",
                            DocumentIssueCountry = "India",
                            DocumentIssueDate = new DateTime(2012, 12, 31),
                            DocumentIssueDateSpecified = true,
                            DocumentIssuePlace = "Mumbai",
                            DocumentNumber = "P483828",
                            DocumentType = HotelService.TraveldocType.P,
                            DocumentTypeSpecified = true,
                            IsEndorsee = false,
                            IsEndorseeSpecified = true
                        },
                        Nationality = "Indian"
                    };
                    hotelBookingType.EventData = new HotelService.BookingEventDataType()
                    {
                        //BookingReference = "12345",
                        //CardType = "VISA",
                        ContactNumber1 = "12345678",
                        ContactNumber2 = "98761532",
                        Email = "abcd@yahoo.com",
                        JobTitle = "Senior Software Consultant",
                        NumberofOccupants = "3",
                        NumberofRooms = "1",
                        OrganisationName = "asdf",
                        OrganisationNumber = "23232323",
                        PaymentDetail = new HotelService.PaymentDetailType[] { new HotelService.PaymentDetailType() { PaymentMethod = HotelService.PaymentMethodType.Cash } },
                        ScheduledArrivalDate = new DateTime(2019, 5, 19),
                        ScheduledDepartureDate = new DateTime(2019, 5, 31)
                    };
                    request.Item = hotelBookingType;

                    string userToken = responseObject.IdentificationToken;

                   client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = userToken;
                    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "Test@123";

                    HotelService.SubmitHotelEventResponse response = client.SubmitHotelEvent(request);

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The error message is SYS9003: Invalid Credentials